# Dynamics AX 2012 R2 CustClassificationGroup table is missing

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012

I am currently working on the POS retail component of Dynamics AX 2012 R2, and it appears that some tables are missing in my store database.

For example, I need to retreive some data that used to be in the CustClassificationGroup table (in the environment from which I got the source code), but it was not created on my store database when using the database utility.

Do you know how I could generate the missing table?
Shall it be created by the AX server with the sync tool? (and if so, how?)

Thanks :)

Thomas KiTe T.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't have all AX tables in your StoreDB.
In StoreDB, you just have relevant tables you need in standard Retail process (cash&carry, inventory, etc...).

If you need to get other standard tables or specific tables, you have to:
- add those in StoreDB SQL schema using specific SQL script added in CreateDatabase DLL
- add those in table distribution (table and field matching, sub-jobbs, etc...)